# Creatng 2 dimensional list in python from 2 1 dimensional lists

Tags: python, list

In my program, I have created 2 1-dimensional lists.  I need to combine this 2 lists into a 2 dimensional list.  I am not sure how to do this.  Here is my code so far to create the 2 lists:

```
def main():
    winners = []
    year = 1903
    yearlist = [] 


    with open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt') as myfile:
         for line in myfile:
             line = line.rstrip('\n')
             winners.append(line)
    for num in range(len(winners)):
         yearlist.append(year)
         year += 1
    print(winners)
    print (yearlist)

 main()
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your list to new list?

```
foo = [winners, yearlist]
```

BTW: list `yearlist` is completely useless as what you store there is just each winner's index + 1903.

Answer (score 0):

Or make a list called `l` like `[[],[]]`, then do some small changes in the loop:

```
def main():
    l = [[],[]]
    year = 1903


    with open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt') as myfile:
         for line in myfile:
             line = line.rstrip('\n')
             l[0].append(line)
    for num in range(len(winners)):
         l[1].append(year)
         year += 1
    print(winners)
    print (yearlist)

main()
```